# Using regex compiled objects and replacing text string with each

Tags: python, regex

I have a `regex` object that is a dict of `re.compile()` objects like the following:

```
p1 = r'\d+'
p1 = re.compile(p1, re.IGNORECASE)
regex['p1'] = p1

p2 = r'[a-z]+'
p2 = re.compile(p2, re.IGNORECASE)
regex['p2'] = p2
```

And I have a string, let's say something like this.

```
1234 abcd 123 abc
```

And I would like to replace all the matches.

```
regex['p1'].sub(text,'NUM')
regex['p2'].sub(text,'ALPHA')
```

So that the final product looks like this:

```
NUM ALPHA NUM ALPHA
```

Comment: It should be `\d+`, not `/d+`, and `[a-z]+`, not `[a-z]`. Also, you don't need the brackets outside the whole regex.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Does the fix work? Or is the problem something else entirely?

Comment: The problem is something else entirely. I am looking for how to replace the regex matches with the strings that i wanted

Comment: What's the result right now? Perhaps you're missing a global specifier?

Comment: `regex['p1'].sub(text,'NUM')` is not the right syntax, i was just writing pseudo code out. I am not sure how to replace a text using re.compile objects

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `sub` should be the replacement, you need to switch 'NUM'/'ALPHA' with text like so:

```
text = "1234 abcd 123 abc"

regex['p1'].sub('NUM', text)
# 'NUM abcd NUM abc'
```

To put things together:

```
regex['p1'].sub('NUM', regex['p2'].sub('ALPHA', text))
# 'NUM ALPHA NUM ALPHA'
```